# Python: Fastest ray to mesh intersection?

Tags: python, raytracing, trimesh

hey guys is there a faster way to get the intersections between rays and a mesh than using trimesh in python?

So right now I am doing this approach:
[Stackoverflow: Python Intersections ray and mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968822/intersection-between-2d-image-point-and-3d-mesh)

Snippet of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import trimesh

# load mesh
mesh = trimesh.load_mesh('test.ply')


# create some rays
ray_origins = np.load('origins.npy') # Shape = (100'000, 3)
ray_directions = np.array('directions.npy') #Shape = (100'000, 3)


# Get the intersections
locations, index_ray, index_tri = mesh.ray.intersects_location(
ray_origins=ray_origins, ray_directions=ray_directions)
```

But it is really slow for many rays.. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed [pyembree](https://github.com/scopatz/pyembree) as is metioned in [ray.py](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/blob/main/examples/ray.py)?

```
requires numpy, but if you install `pyembree` you get the
same API with a roughly 50x speedup.
```

I am also working on the same problem these days, it is fast enough for me after I installed it.