# Trimesh: find an intersection between ray and mesh only on the length of the ray and not in its extension

Tags: python, mesh, raytracing, trimesh

I'm looking for a way to find the intersection between a path of vectors and a trimesh. I have built my code following these two posts:
[Python: Fastest ray to mesh intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553070/python-fastest-ray-to-mesh-intersection)
[Intersection between 2d image point and 3d mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968822/intersection-between-2d-image-point-and-3d-mesh)
I did not have any speed problems. 3.5 million ray intersections are calculated within a few seconds.

In doing so, I ran into the following problem:
As a result I get the intersection independent of the length of the direction vector. So the ray tracing kernel searches for intersections along the vector `r * x`.
But it is important for me to know if the intersection really occurs only within the actual length of the vector ( `r * 1` ).

One possibility would be to use the function `ray.intersects_location()` to search for the intersection and then check if the intersections location is really on my vector or just on an extension of it.

However, I consider this to be overkill. I don't want to know the intersection at all. Actually the information about `intersection` or `no intersection` is enough for me (using `ray.intersection_any()` for this).

Is there a way to implement this with trimesh (or a trimesh compatible library)? Or do I have to calculate the location and check if the intersection is on the vector itself?

Googled for the problem and read a whole while in the [trimesh wiki](https://trimsh.org/index.html). Found nothing relevant.